# Metric defining an sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I want to find for which cases this metric can define an sphere:
$$\frac{1}{P^2}\left(\mathrm d\theta^2+\sin^2 \theta\; \mathrm d\phi^2\right)$$
where $P=\sin^2 \theta+K\cos^2 \theta$, with $K$ the gaussian curvature (constant).

I know from the post [Spherical metric multiply by a function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238432/spherical-metric-multiply-by-a-function) that the curvature doesn't change if you multiply the metric by a differentiable function, so I suppose
that the only condition is that $K$ has to be positive, right?

Comment: It's not true that the curvature doesn't change if you multiply the metric by a differentiable function. I don't know where the person who commented on physics.stackexchange.com got that idea. For example, the pullback of the spherical metric to $\mathbb R^2$ has Gaussian curvature equal to $1$, and it's equal to the Euclidean metric multiplied by a positive smooth function.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

There should be something on the left hand side of a metric and physical dimensions should match.

The metric of a sphere $ \phi=$latitude, $\theta = $longitude.

$$ ds^2 = a^2 d\phi^2  + a^2  \cos^{2}\phi \,d\theta^2 ; K = 1/a^2 \,; $$

$$ K ds^2 = d\phi^2  +  \cos^{2}\phi \,d\theta^2  $$